# Why does "1 / 2" compile when there is no (/) defined in Num?

Tags: haskell, types

Sorry for a newbie question, but I really do not understand overloaded values:

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude> let y = 2
```

Both `x` and `y` have type `Num a => a`. But there is no `(/)` defined in `Num`! So why does the expression `x / y` type check?

```
Prelude> x / y
0.5
```

`(/)` is defined in the class `Fractional`. Is there some implicit conversion from `Num` to `Fractional`?

**UPD**:

So, as expected, I got answers where people are claiming that in `x / y` `a` is specialized to `Fractional a => a`.

I created my own hierarchy of numbers:

```
data MyInt = MyInt Integer deriving Show
data MyDouble = MyDouble Double deriving Show

class MyNum a where
    (+#) :: a -> a -> a -- + renamed to +# to avoid collision with standard +
    myFromInteger :: MyNum a => Integer -> a

class MyNum a => MyFractional a where
    (/#) :: a -> a -> a

instance MyNum MyInt where
    (MyInt a) +# (MyInt b) = MyInt (a + b)
    myFromInteger i = MyInt i

instance MyNum MyDouble where
    (MyDouble a) +# (MyDouble b) = MyDouble (a + b)
    myFromInteger i = MyDouble (fromInteger i)

instance MyFractional MyDouble where
    (MyDouble a) /# (MyDouble b) = MyDouble (a / b)
```

If everything in the asnwers is true, the similar code where `Num` is replaced with `MyNum` should also work. But ghci reports an error:

```
Prelude> :load myint.hs
*Main> let x = myFromInteger 1
*Main> let y = myFromInteger 2
*Main> x /# y

<interactive>:14:1:
    No instance for (MyFractional a0) arising from a use of `it'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance MyFractional MyDouble -- Defined at myint.hs:19:10
    In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't have defaulting rules for your types, which do all the trickery.

Comment: Your edit is more of a new question and the issue has become perhaps the most frequently asked SO Haskell question, namely type defaulting and is commonly embodied in either "my custom types don't get defaults" or "GHCi defaults differently than GHC".

Comment: You shouldn't have a `Num` constraint in `myFromInteger`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are using a newer version of ghci which, by default, has the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` enabled. In such case `x` and `y` indeed have type `Num a => a`:

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude> let y = 2
Prelude> :t x
x :: Num a => a
```

and this type, since it is polymorphic, is *specialized* to `Fractional a => a` when you evaluate `x/y`:

```
Prelude> :t x/y
x/y :: Fractional a => a
```

Since `Num` is a superclass of `Fractional` any `Fractional` type is also a `Num` type and hence specializing the type of `x` and `y` to `Fractional a => a` is possible. It's really no different than doing something like:

```
($) = id :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
```

The function `$` is just a specialization of `id :: c -> c` where `c = a -> b`. In your case you are specialising a constrained type and constraints can be specialized replacing parent classes by subclasses (i.e. more general with more specific constraints) so `Fractional a => a` is a specialization of `Num a => a`.

When ghci has to output the result it must choose *an implementation* of the `/` operator in order to compute the result, and so it must *instantiate* the type to a concrete type. This is done by the [defaulting](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), and so the operations performed are those of the `Double` instance, but they can be changed using a `default` declaration.

---

Note that default works only with *built-in* classes. Quoting from the above link:

> Ambiguities in the class `Num` are most common, so Haskell provides
>   another way to resolve them---with a default declaration:
>
> ```
> default (t1 , ... , tn)
> ```
>
> where `n>=0`, and each `ti` must be a type for which `Num ti` holds. In
>   situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type
>   variable, `v`, is defaultable if:
>
> - `v` appears only in constraints of the form `C v`, where `C` is a class, and
>     at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, `Num` or a subclass of `Num`), and
> - **all of these classes are defined in the `Prelude` or a standard library** (Figures 6.2--6.3, pages -- show the numeric classes, and
>     Figure 6.1, page , shows the classes defined in the Prelude.)

Comment: You get the `No instance for (Fractional Integer) ...` error if you have the monomorphism restriction enabled, but ghci 7.8.3 has is disabled by default.

Comment: @user5402 He didn't specify the version of ghci neither in the question text nor tag.

Comment: No he didn't, but both the monomorphism restriction and defaulting rules are at work here. (And I'm not the one who downvoted you.)

Comment: @user5402 I've edited the answer. The defaulting rules are used when "printing" the value, since at that point ghci must choose *one* implementation of a concrete type in order to output the result.

Comment: @orionll note that defaulting works *only* with built-in types. So the specialization part may work, but ghci cannot choose the instance because it misses defaulting for user-defined types.

Comment: @Bakuriu Can I read about this specialization in more detail somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` have type `Num a => a`, that means they are polymorphic.  It doesn't mean 'some type about which all you know is that it's an instance of `Num`', but 'any type, as long as it's an instance of `Num`'.  So `x / y` then has 'any type as long as it's an instance of `Num` and `Fractional`, which since `Fractional` is a sub-class of `Num` is 'any type as long as it's an instance of `Fractional`, which types like `Rational` and `Double` satisfy.

Incidentally, `1 / 2` taken literally will also type-check, for the same reason that (say) `1 :: Double` and `2 :: Double` type-check: `1` in Haskell isn't limited to integral types, but can be used for any numeric type.

Answer (score -1):

Haskell will Convert the numerator to `Fractional` and preform the Fractional Division.  If you need to divide `Int` try using the infix operatator `div`:

```
Prelude> x div y
```

Comment: `div` is not itself infix, I suspect you ment `\`div\`` but then SO's syntax got in your way?